# adding/removing sections in UITableView at runtime using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, runtime

I'm trying to create a tableView with grouped style as shown below in the image using swift

[image]

how do i go ahead with following issues :

1. I need to add or remove Sections and CellView at runtime in table. 1st section i.e Food will be always same but other remaining sections are dynamic add or removed like Fruits,Vegetables etc.
2. I need to customize Section Header for every new added sections.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update the section headers you will simply have an array of all of your header titles, then update that array to contain the correct titles to the corresponding section index.

So have a instance variable something like...

`var sectionHeaders: String = ["Food", "Fruit", "Vegetables"]`

Then implement this method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView! {

    var label : UILabel = UILabel()
    label.text = self.sectionHeaders[section]
    return label
}
```

After you update the title array you will either want to update or remove a section. To do this use these two methods

```
func insertSections(_ sections: NSIndexSet,withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

and

```
func deleteSections(_ sections: NSIndexSet, withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

Also this method may also come in handy,

```
func moveSection(_ section: Int, toSection newSection: Int)
```